# how to add custom javascripts after woocommerce ones?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I'm using the woocommerce plugin for wordpress.

It loads all its JavaScript files in the footer. I'd like to load my JavaScript after them.

If I add them in functions.php in a 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action via wp_enqueue_script() (and with footer argument setted to true), my files are still loaded before the woocommerce ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the hook priority to a really high number:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so20498083_enqueue', 99999 );
function so20498083_enqueue()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );
}
```